# Base error when trying to get week number

Tags: bash, radix

I'm trying to get the week number of last week. The following command normally had work, but now I'm getting error.

```
lastweeknumber=$((`date +%V`-1))
bash: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
```

This week number is 09, so I've tried to convert to decimal adding `10#` like this `$(10#(date +%V))` but it's not working.

How to fix this?

Comment: Which version of bash? You may not need `date` at all if it's new enough to have `printf %(...)T`.

Comment: Is bash: 4.4.12(3)

Comment: BTW, just subtracting one won't necessarily wrap around properly if you're at the beginning of a year.

Comment: Depending on the implentation of `date` you are using, you don't need shell arithmetic. Both GNU and BSD `date` can compute the number of the previous week for you.

Comment: `date --date "last week" +%V` with GNU, `date -v -1w +%V` for BSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following, which uses bash's built-in functionality in place of the external `date` command, and thus requires a recent shell release but is much faster to run (and will behave consistently without depending on a specific version of `date`).

With that done, though, there's still a need to strip the leading 0 -- which a parameter expansion will do just fine:

```
printf -v seconds_now '%(%s)T' -1
printf -v weeknum_lastweek '%(%V)T' "$(( seconds_now - (60 * 60 * 24 * 7) ))"
echo "The index of last week is ${weeknum_lastweek#0}"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I wasn't aware of `%(...)T` feature.

Comment: @anubhava, it's a placeholder -- it would be needed if your format string accepted any other arguments after the `%(...)T`, so having it there is a good habit to be in.

Comment: You can use `%-V` in the formatting directive to suppress padding zeroes. see ["Glibc notes"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html#NOTES).

Comment: Heh. I was looking at a BSD strftime manual, which is presumably why I missed that. Though... looking again, it's there near the end (on a very non-GNU platform!): *`%-*`   GNU libc extension.  Do not do any padding when performing numerical outputs.*

Comment: Still, I'm hesitant to edit the answer to add a GNUism, when one of the claims I'm making is to work on any host with a recent enough bash regardless of the OS vendor.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `date +%V` returns `09` and shell is interpreting any value starting with `0` as an octal number. Note that `09` is an invalid octal number hence you get that error `value too great for base`.

You can just force module 10 arithmetic in `(( ... ))`:

```
echo $(( 10#$(date +%V) - 1 ))
```

```
8
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on how the OP's earlier ```$((10#`date +%V`-1))``` attempt stated in their question failed.

Comment: Hmm; now they've edited it into something where the cause of the initial failure is a little more clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way that handles wrapping around year correctly:

```
lastweeknumber=$(date -d "1 week ago" +%V)
```